# Access: Combo box and many-to-many relationship

Tags: ms-access, combobox, many-to-many

I am fairly new to MS Access and looking for a solution regarding a form I am trying to build. The form should be used to show different user entries and to create or modify users.

The problem I am blocking is for a combo box and a many-to-many relationship.

I have several tables which combined provide me the information I use to build the form.

My first table **Users** provides me information about *first name, last name etc. *

A second table **Servers** includes the list of different *country servers* a user can have access to.

Since an user can have access to different servers/countries and a country/server can have different users I am confronted with a many-to-many relationship. Therefore I created a junction table which includes the *userID* as FK (from the **User** table) and the *ID* as FK (of the country/server from the **Servers** table).

What I am trying to achieve now but where I am blocking is:

- to have a combobox which lists all available servers/countries
- mark the entries which are linked to the user record which is shown

e.g.

> **Servers**: Belgium, Germany, Netherlands, Sweden, UK
>
> **User**: John Doe => access to Germany & UK
>
> - list/combobox should show all countries but select only the ones John doe has access to (when record John Doe is selected)

Is there any way to achieve this and what needs to be done ?
I am also open for any other solution if this cannot be done via a combobox.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cross-posted http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=67231

Comment: A list box and a combo box are two very different things. Are you looking to be able to add/remove available servers to each user (which would need a list box) or select one server out of those available to the user (combo box)?

Comment: Yes, sorry regarding the confusion for the combo box. 
It is because in the beginning there was the multi-valued field used for this point. But as mvf cannot be used with queries I try to change the whole form.
I want to select one or multiple server for a user from a list of servers.